# Problem reading from serial port using win32 api (C langauge)

Tags: c, winapi, arduino, serial-communication

I'm trying to write to and read from serial port (arduino) using win32 api and C langauge. I want to send a number to the arduino, calculate the square there and read it by C program. But with the code below, either the program leaves the loop neither reads the incoming data. My C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 256
int main(){
    
    HANDLE hComm = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    
    hComm = CreateFile("\\\\.\\COM5", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    
    if(hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        printf("CreateFile() failed\n");
        return -1;
    }else{
        printf("CreateFile() succeeded\n");
    }
    
    DCB dcb;
    memset(&dcb, 0, sizeof(DCB));
    
    if(!GetCommState(hComm, &dcb)){
        printf("GetCommState() failed\n");
        return -1;
    }
    
    printf("## PLEASE SELECT FROM THE FOLLOWING ##\n");
    printf("## MENU  :              ##\n");
    printf("(1) TURN ON LED ON ARDUINO\n");
    printf("(2) TURN OFF LED ON ARDUINO\n");
    printf("(3) FLASH ARDUINO 3 TIMES\n");
    printf("(4) SEND A NUMBER TO ARDUINO TO COMPUTE SQUARE BY ARDUINO\n");
    printf("(5) Button press counter (bonus item) **not working**\n");
    printf("(0) EXIT\n");
    
    char writeBuff[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char readBuff;
    char buff[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char intSend[6];
    int choice;
    int writtenBytes = 0;
    int allReadBytes = 0;
    int readByte = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char abc[10];
    unsigned char loop = 0;
    int a;
    int index = 0;
    
    do{
        printf("PLEASE SELECT: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        
        switch(choice){
            
            case 1:
                    strcpy(writeBuff, "a");
                    
                    if(WriteFile(hComm, writeBuff, 1, (LPDWORD)&writtenBytes, NULL)){
                        if(writtenBytes == 0){
                            printf("WriteFile() timed out \n");
                            return -1;
                        }
                    }else{
                        printf("WriteFile() failed\n");
                        return -1;
                    }
                    printf("%d bytes were written\n", writtenBytes);
                    writtenBytes = 0;
                    break;
                    
            case 2:
                    strcpy(writeBuff, "b");
                    
                    if(WriteFile(hComm, writeBuff, 1, (LPDWORD)&writtenBytes, NULL)){
                        if(writtenBytes == 0){
                            printf("WriteFile() timed out \n");
                            return -1;
                        }
                    }else{
                        printf("WriteFile() failed\n");
                        return -1;
                    }
                    printf("%d bytes were written\n", writtenBytes);
                    writtenBytes = 0;
                    break;
                    
            case 3:
                    strcpy(writeBuff, "c");
                    
                    if(WriteFile(hComm, writeBuff, 1, &writtenBytes, NULL)){
                        if(writtenBytes == 0){
                            printf("WriteFile() timed out \n");
                            return -1;
                        }
                    }else{
                        printf("WriteFile() failed\n");
                        return -1;
                    }
                    printf("%d bytes were written\n", writtenBytes);
                    writtenBytes = 0;
                    break;
                    
            case 4:
                    
                printf_s("Please enter a number\n");
                scanf_s(" %s", &abc);
            
                writeBuff[0] = abc[0];
                writeBuff[1] = abc[1];
                writeBuff[2] = abc[2];

                
                WriteFile(hComm,   
                    writeBuff,           
                    sizeof(writeBuff),   
                    &writtenBytes,          
                    NULL);
                    
                    do{
                        ReadFile(hComm, &readBuff, sizeof(readBuff), &readByte, NULL);
                        
                        buff[loop]=readBuff;
                        ++loop;
                        
                    }while(readByte > 0);
                    --loop;
                    
                    a = index;
                    for(index = a; index < loop; ++index){
                        printf_s("%c", buff[index]);
                    }
                    
                    break;
        }
            
    }while(choice != 0);
    
    if(!CloseHandle(hComm)){
        
        printf("CloseHandle() failed\n");
        return -1;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

With debugger, I noticed that ReadFile reads what I send from C program and not what arduino sends to the serial port. Also I tested turning on led with, let's say, the number 12 and it works so I'm sure that I'm able to send data with WriteFile. My arduino code:

```
int i;
String value;
long sqCalc;
long karesi;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  
  if(Serial.available() > 0){

     value = Serial.readString();
     Serial.println(value);
    
    if(value == "a"){
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
      Serial.println("LED is ON");
      delay(250);
    }else if(value == "b"){
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
      Serial.println("LED is OFF");
    }else if(value == "c"){
      if(digitalRead(LED_BUILTIN) == HIGH){
        for(i=0;i<3;i++){
          digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
          delay(250);
          digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
          delay(250);
        }
      }
      
      if(digitalRead(LED_BUILTIN) == LOW){
        for(i=0;i<3;i++){
          digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
          delay(250);
          digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
          delay(250);
        }
      }
     }
      sqCalc = value.toInt();
      if(sqCalc > 0){
          karesi = pow(sqCalc, 2);
          Serial.println(karesi, DEC);
      }
      
    }
  }
```

Lastly, tested arduino code with PuTTy and it works fine.

Comment: Does ReadFile return? - What's the return code and GetLastError()?

Comment: Put full codes.

Comment: `buff[loop]=readBuff;` You never check that the `loop` index is within bounds. `a = index;` This keeps going up since `index` doesn't seem to be reset anywhere, and again `buff[index]` is not bounds-checked. Also, the return values of `Write/ReadFile` are not checked for errors.

Comment: Your comport string looks odd. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/configuring-a-communications-resource

Comment: I was checking for errors before but deleted that part trying to solve the reading problem, I'll fix them and my messy coding.

Comment: @jwd The device path looks quite OK to me (see [Win32 Device Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#win32-device-namespaces) for details).

Comment: @IInspectable, I hate getting old!

Comment: Is your problem solved? It looks like you didn't clear the `buff` after using it up. And `a = index` does not seem to work. You can modify it to `index = 0;`

Comment: Nope. As I've mentioned after WriteFile, the ReadFile reads what I send in case 4. Also the while loop never ends. readByte is always 1 and reads some weird stuff too.

Comment: `ReadFile` is reading the garbage value, trying to use `ReadFile` to receive all the data.   `char readBuff[BUFFER_SIZE] = {}; ReadFile(hComm, readBuff, strlen(readBuff)+2, &readByte, NULL);

    for (int index = 0; index < readByte; ++index) {
        printf_s("%c", readBuff[index]);
    }`  . Don't forget to delete `do...while`. Hope to help you.